# Cant centre div in another div

Tags: css, html, position

I have a div in that div there are two other div. One has got to be on the left side and the other must be in the center but is with margin 0 when i check

```
<div class="row">
                        <!-- START LOGO -->
                     <div id="logo" class="span3">..</div>
                        </div>
                                                    <!-- END LOGO -->

                        <!-- START MENU - TOPBAR -->
                        <div id="nav-topbar" class="span9">...</div>                   
                </div>
```

and this is the css

```
.row{
width:100%;
}
.span3{
float:left;
position:absolute;
width 270px;
}
.span9{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:870px;
}
```

Comment: You have too many `</div>`, you need to first remove the closing `div` after the logo. `float:left` and `position:absolute` don't work together. Your classes have no reference to anything `span3`, `span9`

Comment: Also your `width` property in `.span3` is missing the `:`. The classes do reference the classes in the markup, but the names are misleading as you are assigning divs classes with the name "span".

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- START LOGO -->
    <div id="logo" class="span3">..</div>
    <!-- END LOGO -->

    <!-- START MENU - TOPBAR -->
    <div id="nav-topbar" class="span9">...</div>     
     <!-- END TOPBAR -->     
</div>
```

**CSS**

*Note: I have added black borders so you can see the outline of the divs.*

```
.row{
    width:100%;
}
.span3{
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    width:270px;
}
.span9{
    border:1px solid black;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-435px;
    position:absolute;
    width:870px;
}
```